# NullInjectorError: No provider for MatDialog! error showing while using guard with mat dialog

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, frontend

I have an error:

```
VM654 vendor.js:29876 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AccountsModule)[CreateAccountGuard -> CreateAccountGuard -> CreateAccountGuard -> ModalService -> MatDialog -> MatDialog -> MatDialog]:   NullInjectorError: No provider for MatDialog!
```

I do not get what is wrong and why I see it.

Basically, in CreateAccountGuard (which is in Accounts Module) I use Modal service to open confirmation modal.

Confirmation modal component and ModalService  are in another module - Modals module.
I have added Confirmation modal component to declarations and entryComponents. MatDialogModule is also added there in imports.

While running Jasmine test - no issues. But on the website -  I see this error.

Unfortunately, cannot share the code. Maybe you have any ideas what to do from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was related to the fact that I was adding MatDialog module to the Modals module (My feature one).

I have added it to imports in the app.module and it worked.